# How can i search file content using Zend studio RSE

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio

I have many folder directories under my Remote System Explorer .

How to Search entire files in a directory for a keyword using Zend studio search?

Comment: Searching many files on a remote server through FTP? That would take a very long time. Essentially, it would have to download every file, search through them, then give you the result. I don't thing Zend Studio allows that as a feature.

Comment: so you saying that .. RSE is connected to server as an ft connection and search is not possible.. grep will be better ..

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. If you have shell access Grep would be much better. :-) Zend should consider adding a search for connections over SFTP where it runs grep for you.

Answer (score 0):

Bump for @Clint's answer. I have used ZS for a few years, and have never seen a remote search function (goes and double-checks). I looked at the options of a project that I have connected to a remote server and at least on the standard search dialog I don't see it.

[image]